# Xamarin.Forms Android App: Slow Launch and Actions

Tags: c#, performance, xamarin

Experiencing slow app launch and sluggish behavior during actions in a Xamarin.Forms app on Android. Removed default Xamarin startup controls for a minimalistic UI. Seeking advice on profiling tools or techniques to identify and address performance issues.

Comment: Have you tried this : [Hardware acceleration for emulator performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows) to maximize Android Emulator performance?

Comment: It's not just emulator.

Comment: Then your question should focus on one problem only. Besides here is official document about [Profiling Android Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/profiling).